# What are some interesting uses for an iPod touch 1G with broken wifi?

Tags: ipod-touch, jailbreak

I have a 1st generation iPod touch in which wifi does not seem to work. Fixing it would cost too much and I don't want to just throw it away. It is jailbroken at the moment, but this does not help as it seems you can only install apps from cydia or rock store when connected via wifi. You can install apps from Apple's App store when you are connected to iTunes on your computer, but I would like this ipod to be more than just an "app runner".

I am a programmer so what I have in mind is trying to write some software that could run on this iphone and possibly convert it into a completely different device. I know this is very vague but maybe together we will manage to come up with some interesting ideas...

**EDIT**: Let's concentrate on the "what cool things can be done with this ipod" instead of "how to fix the wifi". That is what my inner nerd asked me to write :)

Comment: Pardon me if this sounds silly, but have you tried restoring? If not, maybe that will fix the WiFi...hopefully lol.

Comment: I tried a couple of times. No candy...

Comment: @silvo I thought the phrase was "No dice", but I like your version better. :D

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [Linux on the iPhone](http://linuxoniphone.blogspot.com/), or since your question asked for "interesting" and not for "useful", [Windows 95 on iPhone](http://www.engadget.com/2009/07/13/iphone-becomes-the-worst-parallels-installation-youve-ever-seen/):

> Give a guy an iPhone, a jailbreak, and
>   an open-source, cross-platform x86
>   emulator, and it's just a matter of
>   time before hilarity ensues.

Comment: Windows 95 on the iPhone, ace.

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing a remote control ir attachment somewhere for sale.  You could use it as a fancy remote.

Comment: Those, unfortunately, require WiFi to operate - the 1st-gen touch didn't have Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

I would dock it to a Sony or Bose ipod-dock-alarm-clock, leaving it permanently on my bedside table as my alarm-clock-ipod.

For extra coolness points, you should turn it into a robot.  See the people making "cell phone robots?".   Yours would have to be untethered since you have no wifi or other connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a pretty decent gaming device. There are a lot of non-networking-dependent games that you can use.